# What does this mean: CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: java, security

I have an existing set of services (utilizing Spring Boot), some of which expose REST endpoints. I have application properties to turn SSL on or off, along with configuration code that sets up security mechanisms used when a `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` is created to make a REST call.

As far as I can tell (I hope), I have the certificate key and trust stores set up correctly, however I'm getting an exception when a client service attempts to make a REST call to a server service.

The exception thrown by the "client" is:

```
Exception in thread "task-1" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8443/v1/missionServices/missionPlanning/planMission": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

*What does this error mean and what can cause it?*

Do I have a trust store that does **not** contain a public key for the "server" service being invoked? Is there something else going on?

If more information is needed (code, config, etc.) please let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: This seems with cacert.jar file issue, ensure that it should present in server

Comment: Where does this jar come from? Shouldn't this be provided automatically by Spring Boot?

Comment: The exception means that the certificate authority (CA) that issued the server certificate is not trusted by the client.  Is the server using a self-signed certificate? The truststore that ships with Java is located in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`. If you are using a self-signed server cert you'll need to add that to the truststore (assuming your client is written in Java).